# Getting ’Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=' error` when trying official TVM tutorial

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the first example in [TVM](https://docs.tvm.ai/tutorials/relay_quick_start.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-relay-quick-start-py), but at the very begining I'm faced with these errors. I have built the tvm with **LLVM ON** and **OpenCL On** (installed Intel sdk for opencl applications - opencl 2.1). The build process went smoothly without a hitch, so I guess everything is in place.

However I get these errors when I tried to run this snippet from this example: [Quick Start Tutorial for Compiling Deep Learning Models](https://docs.tvm.ai/tutorials/relay_quick_start.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-relay-quick-start-py) :

```py
opt_level = 3
target = tvm.target.intel_graphics()
with relay.build_config(opt_level=opt_level):
    graph, lib, params = relay.build_module.build(
        mod, target, params=params)
```

```
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('conv2d', (1, 3, 224, 224, 'float32'), (64, 3, 7, 7, 'float32'), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('conv2d', (1, 64, 56, 56, 'float32'), (64, 64, 3, 3, 'float32'), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('conv2d', (1, 64, 56, 56, 'float32'), (64, 64, 1, 1, 'float32'), (1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('conv2d', (1, 64, 56, 56, 'float32'), (128, 64, 3, 3, 'float32'), (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('conv2d', (1, 128, 28, 28, 'float32'), (128, 128, 3, 3, 'float32'), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('conv2d', (1, 64, 56, 56, 'float32'), (128, 64, 1, 1, 'float32'), (2, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('conv2d', (1, 128, 28, 28, 'float32'), (256, 128, 3, 3, 'float32'), (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('conv2d', (1, 256, 14, 14, 'float32'), (256, 256, 3, 3, 'float32'), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('conv2d', (1, 128, 28, 28, 'float32'), (256, 128, 1, 1, 'float32'), (2, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('conv2d', (1, 256, 14, 14, 'float32'), (512, 256, 3, 3, 'float32'), (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('conv2d', (1, 512, 7, 7, 'float32'), (512, 512, 3, 3, 'float32'), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('conv2d', (1, 256, 14, 14, 'float32'), (512, 256, 1, 1, 'float32'), (2, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=unknown, workload=('dense', (1, 512, 'float32'), (1000, 512, 'float32'), 0, 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
```

I also tried sending the graphics model to see if that's the cause, to no avail! I still get the same error messages, this time with the model I provided, i.e:

```py
opt_level = 3
target = tvm.target.intel_graphics(model='Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580')
with relay.build_config(opt_level=opt_level):
    graph, lib, params = relay.build_module.build(
        mod, target, params=params)
```

```sh
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('conv2d', (1, 3, 224, 224, 'float32'), (64, 3, 7, 7, 'float32'), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('conv2d', (1, 64, 56, 56, 'float32'), (64, 64, 3, 3, 'float32'), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('conv2d', (1, 64, 56, 56, 'float32'), (64, 64, 1, 1, 'float32'), (1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('conv2d', (1, 64, 56, 56, 'float32'), (128, 64, 3, 3, 'float32'), (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('conv2d', (1, 128, 28, 28, 'float32'), (128, 128, 3, 3, 'float32'), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('conv2d', (1, 64, 56, 56, 'float32'), (128, 64, 1, 1, 'float32'), (2, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('conv2d', (1, 128, 28, 28, 'float32'), (256, 128, 3, 3, 'float32'), (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('conv2d', (1, 256, 14, 14, 'float32'), (256, 256, 3, 3, 'float32'), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('conv2d', (1, 128, 28, 28, 'float32'), (256, 128, 1, 1, 'float32'), (2, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('conv2d', (1, 256, 14, 14, 'float32'), (512, 256, 3, 3, 'float32'), (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('conv2d', (1, 512, 7, 7, 'float32'), (512, 512, 3, 3, 'float32'), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('conv2d', (1, 256, 14, 14, 'float32'), (512, 256, 1, 1, 'float32'), (2, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), 'NCHW', 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
Cannot find config for target=opencl -device=intel_graphics -model=Intel(R) Iris(R) Pro Graphics 580, workload=('dense', (1, 512, 'float32'), (1000, 512, 'float32'), 0, 'float32'). A fallback configuration is used, which may bring great performance regression.
```

I even tried changing the op_level, which didn't affect anything. What should I be doing to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is not an error, but a warning. Because TVM could not find a log file which contains the optimized schedules, it will just use the default (*fallback*) schedules.

To get rid of the warning, you need to use AutoTVM (as in [this example](https://docs.tvm.ai/tutorials/autotvm/tune_relay_x86.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-autotvm-tune-relay-x86-py)) to find the optimized schedules. After that, you can proceed to compiling.